# Reading specific line from text file java

Tags: java, file, text

Hey guys I have a Text file structured like this

1,2,Name,3

How can I get all lines with number 2 in column 2?

So far I can read the file and update it ect.

Comment: Please post the code which you've used to read the file.

Comment: Your question is too vague, SO doesn't work in this way.

Comment: read each line, if line is not null, then split using ',' as demiliter and check array[1]=2, if so then add that line to a collection... repeat for all lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String[]> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

step 1 : read file line by line

```
String row = "row read from file";
```

step 2 : split every line by character ','

```
String[] temp = row.split(',');
```

step 3 : store the splitted array in your desired datatype object

```
tempArrayList.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go in this way..

Read file line by line.
After reading each line use string tokenizer and get second column.
And check weather it is '2' or not.

I hope it helps you, simple way...

Comment: Thanks for that it worked but in the end I used regex and just printed all lines that contain a certain pattern, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by columns you mean in context to a csv file where columns in a row are separated by a comma then you can do something like below

```
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
        String readLine = null;
        int count = 0;
        while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            String[] words = readLine.split(",");
            if(words[1]!=null && words[1].equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                System.out.println("Criteria met at Line number " + count);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```